# Zend Form Elemenet addValidators list value

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

In Zend_Form_Element. I see `addValidators()`, but not in Zend example, and the book. They only show me about "NotEmpty" , and "EmailAddress".

Also have `->addFilter('StripTags')` and "StringTrim" or "Int"

I want to know is there more value for `addValidators()` & `addFilter()` (not only "NotEmpty" and "EmailAddress", right?)

But I can't find any link on Zend website.. Their document is hard to use.

Any one give me a list of those values or link to some page I can learn.

Comment: It really isn't true that it's hard to find in the documentation! http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html and http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.html

Comment: I read it already, but they are not Zend Form Element. I know you're pro, but this world is full of noobs.

Comment: Every validator and filter can be used for form data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it also in your project in library/Zend/Validate and library/Zend/Filter

Comment: Come on, how's that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The [Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/) is the place to be looking for useful information.

See the [Standard Validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html) page from the [Zend_Validate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html) section which shows all the built in validation classes you can use, and a similar page for [Standard Filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html) from the [Zend_Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.html) section.

The [API Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/) gives you a full outline of all the classes and their methods, but if you are new to ZF it can be hard to find what you are looking for in the API docs.  The reference guide is where you will probably be spending a lot of your time reading and learning from examples.

`Zend_Form_Element` works seamlessly with `Zend_Validate` classes, so you are able to 0 or more `Zend_Validate_*` classes to your form elements to validate them against a set of rules instead of manually writing code to validate input.